# Display arabic correctly on ip phones

Tags: voip, cisco

i am facing an issue on cisco ip phones, when trying to display arabic characters it displays corrupted as ???????? so i was wondering How to display arabic correctly on ip phones ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed using the following code:

```
String newStr=new String(
            str.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "utf-8");
```